# adding listbox control programmatically and retaining Viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

My page has a button control.

When the button is clicked a listbox is added to a page's panel.

The problem is, at the first click a listbox appears, at the second or more clicks nothing happens, just the first list box is displayed.

I know the issue is probably with the viewstate, but I've no idea where to fix the code?

```
  public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        List<ListBox> myList;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myList = new List<ListBox>();
            Button1.Click += Add_ListBox1;
        }

        public void Add_ListBox1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox temp_listBox = new ListBox();
            myList.Add(temp_listBox);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(temp_listBox);
        }


    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is simply confusing. Exactly what you want to do ?. "I know the issue is probably with the viewstate, but I've no idea where to fix the code?" Here where you are passing viewstate variable ?. And as per your code. You will get one list box alone . What you want is more list box to appear on each click ?

Comment: Yes, at every click add a new LsitBox

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the asp.net page lifecyle [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On each button click the whole page will be recreated so your panel will be empty. Then the button click event handler is processed and just a listbox is added in the panel.

A possible solution to your problem is defined here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502251/How-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-ASP-NET-and.

Answer (score 0):

why don't u try this code
as u said viewstate problem ... if it is this should work..

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
 List<ListBox> myList;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myList = new List<ListBox>();
       Button1.Click += Add_ListBox1;
    }

    public void Add_ListBox1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 1;


        if (ViewState["Clicks"] != null)
        {
            count = (int)ViewState["Clicks"] + 1;

            ListBox temp_listBox = new ListBox();
            myList.Add(temp_listBox);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(temp_listBox);

        }


        ViewState["Clicks"] = count;


    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Add_ListBox1(e,e);
    }
}
```